# Multiple regions in a zone with different widths

Tags: theming

I am using Omega / Delta / Context on my local environment and created a sub-theme with omega-tools. I want to add more regions to the footer section. I want the regions to be similar to that of Postscript One-to-Postscript Fourth.

Im not sure if ill be able to explain well in words, hence i have taken screen-shots of what i intend to do and what am i doing to get it and the output. http://pho.to/2qA1P (Sorry for the external link, i don't have enough reputation yet to share more images)

*How do i want the layout:*
I want the regions Footer Links One, Footer Links Two, Footer Links Three, Footer Links Four to appear between: Footer First and Footer Second. 
In this order:

```
    Footer Zone        Column Count: 12 Cols
    Footer First       Width : 12 Cols
    Footer Links One   Width : 3 Cols
    Footer Links Two   Width : 3 Cols
    Footer Links Three Width : 3 Cols
    Footer Links Four  Width : 3 Cols
    Footer Second      Width : 12 Cols
    Footer Zone
```

and i have accordingly changed the region `Weights` and `Widths` in above regions, under `Zone Configuration`.

However, in the actual result the Footer Links regions are not displayed within Footer First and Footer Second regions.

Strangely, when i created a Delta and applied it to a Path with Context, i get the output exactly as i intended.

Please help me on how to fix this.

Alternatively, i was thinking to get Footer Link regions under a separate Zone and place 2 new zones above and below this zone with regions Footer First and Footer Second. Not sure if this is the correct way.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved.

What i did to resolve the issue:

I had to setup the Zone in the sub-theme settings first. So i went to the sub-theme settings and assigned Weights from 0-5 for Regions Footer First uptil Footer Second.

Once this was done, the changes were reflecting properly.